# How to Know Whether a Specific Export Filter is Registered in Windows?

Tags: vba, export, powerpoint

I am using Slide.Export to export a powerpoint slide into a file. Based on its doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.export, it said the second parameter is a filter name and "The specified graphics format must have an export filter registered in the Windows registry.".

Now how can know if a format that is registered in Windows? Or in other word, I only want to export the file to a popular format, such as .BMP or .JPG, so that it can be easily opened via program. How to make sure such export filter is registered in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It appears filters used to be found in the registry here:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Graphics Filters

But you'll only see GIF, PNG and JPEG and they point to *.FLT files which seem to be some kind of legacy format. If you search your file system for *flt.dll files you'll find many more, including offFilt.dll which may be the filter for exporting to Office XML file formats.

Note too that the export choices doesn't match up with what PowerPoint includes so while you can save a picture on a slide as an SVG, if you try the Slide.Export method with "svg" as the filter, you'll get this error:

> Slide (unknown member) : PowerPoint can't export the slide(s) because
> no installed converter supports this file type.

[image]

So the full list (on Windows) appears to be:

png, jpg, gif, tif, bmp, emf, wmf

Lots of guess work but yes, the Microsoft documentation for this method is woeful.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's help for that command is nearly non-existant. There isn't even the usual AutoComplete list of FilterName parameters. About all you can do is try a succession of filtername strings to see which ones export. All of the ones below work:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Export FileName:="Test.jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
        .Export FileName:="Test.bmp", FilterName:="BMP"
        .Export FileName:="Test.gif", FilterName:="GIF"
        .Export FileName:="Test.tif", FilterName:="TIF"
        .Export FileName:="Test.wmf", FilterName:="WMF"
        .Export FileName:="Test.emf", FilterName:="EMF"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Note too that "PPTX" is a valid graphics filter for Windows but not for macOS, where you'll get an error. Curious given the sparseness and incorrect information in the Microsoft article mentioned by alancc.